# how to pass a values from one form to another form without creating new instance of a form in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

ya well i am very much aware calling an another form is quite  a common requirement by using

  `Form3 f3 = new Form3();`

   `f3.ShowDialog();`

but the difficulty i am facing is i don't want to create a new instance of form3 every time and i can't even create constructor globally as i am passing some parameters to it.

My requirement is **form1 textbox** value should be passed to **form3 datagrid**.

How to do that?

My **form1 code** is

```
    String l=null;
    String m= null;
    Decimal n=0;
    String o=null;
    private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {                       
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        Class1 a = new Class1(mold, mcur, mshape, mwidth, mcolor);
        ds.Add(a);
        int c = (mold.X > mcur.X ? mcur.X : mold.X);
        int b = (mold.Y > mcur.Y ? mcur.Y : mold.Y);
        int w = Math.Abs(mold.X - mcur.X);
        int h = Math.Abs(mold.Y - mcur.Y);
        String line = LayerName.Text + "\t" + Material.Text+ "\t" + w.ToString() + "\t" + h.ToString() + "\t" + c.ToString() + "\t" + b.ToString() + "\t" + numericUpDown1.Value + "\t" + comboBox3.Text + Environment.NewLine;
         l=LayerName.Text;
         m=Material.Text;
         n=numericUpDown1.Value;
         o=comboBox3.Text;
         Form3 f3 = new Form3(l, m, n, o);
         f3.ShowDialog();
        string path = @"C:\Users\pri\Desktop\efg.txt";
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            File.Create(path);
            TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path);
            tw.WriteLine(line);
            tsw.Close();
        }
        else if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path, true);
            tw.WriteLine(line);
            tw.Close();
        }  
    }
```

form3:

```
    public Form3(string myString, string rek, decimal myvalue, string text1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        string[] Rows = new string[2];

        for (int i = 0; i < Rows.Length; i++)
        {
            DataGridViewRow Row = new DataGridViewRow();
            Row.CreateCells(dataGridView1);
            if (myString != null)
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = myString;
            if (rek != null)
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = rek;
            if (myvalue != 0)
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = myvalue;
            if (text1 != null)
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = text1;
            // int index = this.dataGridView1.Rows.Count;

            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(Rows);
        }
    }
```

problem:the textbox values is replacing in same row everytime without updating in new row.

Answer (score 0):

1st Way:

In Form 1,

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var frm2 = new Form2(dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        frm2.Show();
    }
}
```

Form2

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2(string s)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox1.Text = s;
    }
}
```

2nd Way:

```
public event EventHandler<Form2EventArgs> Form2Event;

public class Form2EventArgs : EventArgs
{
   public object Data {get;set;}
}

Event listener in Form1:

private void GetData(object sender, Form2EventArgs args)
{
    object data = args.Data;

}

 calling the event,

   Form2 form2 = new Form2();
   form2.Form2Event += GetData;
   if(Form2Event != null)
   form2Event(this, new Form2EventArgs {Data = data});
```

Comment: I am not familiar with the second way.but in first way my datagrid is in 2nd form so it is not taking.and i have tried the other way to like passing textbox value as argument.but it only works for one row.same row is updating

Answer (score 0):

Make a class containing your properties(mold , ... ), Maybe Something like "Class1".
Cache your data as List somewhere in touch, so manipulate the list and finally fetch it all to the grid.

Answer (score 0):

You could work with static variables or you can store this in a class.